# Apache override ErrorDocument + RewriteCond (or LocationMatch)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, response, apache2.2, errordocument

I'm looking for the way of overriding 
**ErrorDocument 503** if certain condition happens.

Scenario:
When I do create manually a file-flag in system (for maintenance purpose)

> touch /var/state/technical

this cuts-off calls to "backend", throws **HTTP 503** - that's perfect. 
Vhost apache code:

```
    ErrorDocument 503 /some_error_page.html

    RewriteCond /var/state/technical -f
    RewriteRule ^/some_page.* http://127.0.0.1:1/ [P]
```

That works like charm, but i can not distinguish between

503 - on "backend" failure

and

503 - on "technical" maintenance

---

My research for now:
You can change ErrorDocument  on LocationMatch:

```
<LocationMatch ^/some_url(.*)>
    ErrorDocument 503 /technical_page.html
</LocationMatch>
```

*The 'ideal word' would works like: (this is bad apache syntax)*

```
RewriteCond /var/state/technical -f
ErrorDocument 503 /technical_page.html
```

For Now:

```
RewriteCond /var/state/technical -f
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:80/technical_page.html [PT]
```

works, but that returns 
**HTTP 200** response code.
**If** I could override response code here, that would be enough.

I can not use simple redirect R=503

```
RewriteRule !^/error|ping/.* /technical.html [PT,R=503]
```

because it would display default 503 error page (*ErrorDocument 503 /some_error_page.html*)

Any suggestions?
apache2.2

Comment: _“If I could override response code here, that would be enough”_ – I doubt that it would be, actually … because it will _not_ tell the requesting client that there was an error with the resource it requested, but only with the one that it has been redirected to.

Comment: Well, _If I could override response code here_  I was hoping to override HTTP 200, on **Return** from the whole request: The ` RewriteRule .* ` part, not the proxy part `http://127.0.0.1:80/technical_page.html'

Comment: No, even if you could that would be wrong, because the client would not know that the resource it originally requested had a 503 error, it would only see the 3xx redirect status code … and that should not be what you want, if you want to handle this correctly.

Comment: I think your best bet is to make your error document itself a script (instead of a static file) – that way it can check what the error reason was (for example by checking if your file `/var/state/technical` exists), and react accordingly.

Comment: _No, even if you could that would be wrong_
Yes, I do agree that might be against _good practise_ and possible security risk, although it would be nice If I could do that (just for this purpouse). 

Do You can suggest other strategy that would allow for returning 503 with variable (configurable) error page?